# PHP Array Creation from JSON with specific queries

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON file which I retrieve

```
// Sample JSON Results
 [
     {
         "serial": "A",
         "timeStamp": "2018-07-28 04:00:00",
         "value1": "0.000000",
         "value2": "0.000192",
         "value3": "1.000000"
     },
     {
         "serial": "B",
         "timeStamp": "2018-07-28 04:00:00",
         "value1": "0.000000",
         "value2": "0.000191",
         "value3": "1.000000"
     },
     {
         "serial": "C",
         "timeStamp": "2018-07-28 04:00:00",
         "value1": "0.000000",
         "value2": "0.000191",
         "value3": "1.000000"
     },    
     {
         "serial": "A",
         "timeStamp": "2018-07-28 05:00:00",
         "value1": "0.000000",
         "value2": "0.000191",
         "value3": "1.000000"
     },
     {
         "serial": "B",
         "timeStamp": "2018-07-28 05:00:00",
         "value1": "0.000000",
         "value2": "0.000191",
         "value3": "1.000000"
     },
     {
         "serial": "C",
         "timeStamp": "2018-07-28 05:00:00",
         "value1": "0.000000",
         "value2": "0.000191",
         "value3": "1.000000"
 }
 ]
```

My question is how do I loo through this array to only Retrieve Serial as an example Serial A results with All 3 Values

```
// Sample JSON Results[
    {
        "timeStamp": "2018-07-28 04:00:00",
        "value1": "0.000000",
        "value2": "0.000192",
        "value3": "1.000000"
    },
    {
        "timeStamp": "2018-07-28 05:00:00",
        "value1": "0.000000",
        "value2": "0.000191",
        "value3": "1.000000"
    }
]
```

Output format as an php array, im just not sure how to query the serial as `A` as an example, and then retrieve all unique timestamps with their values for `value1`, `value2`, `value3`:

```
[
[timestamp,
value1,
value2,
value3],
[timestamp
value1,
value2,
value3],
[timestamp,
value1,
value2,
value3]
]
```

Comment: any example format in which you want result.

Comment: Updated thread, Not 100% sure if Im clear there, but essentially i have a array of serials with their values, usually A / B / C, timestamp for A/B&C is always the same, however im trying to output only A as an example showing the timestamp, value 1, value2 & value 3, then loo through all results.

Comment: So you want the query to bring this format of data from mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` function

Below is the sample. It will return the selected data set from the list, you have to pass param, $list is your objects as and array, $key , the key you have find in your list, $value is the value for that key you have to find

```
function filterList($list, $key, $value) {
   return array_filter($list, function($a) {
         return $a[$value] == $value;
    });

 }
```

Hope it helps you !

Answer (score 0):

The process actually involves more than a couple of steps.

Step 1: Convert the JSON data to PHP array.

Step 2: Filter the array and only keep those that have serial = A.

Step 3: Remove the serial index for each array found in Step 2.

Step 4: Convert data back to JSON.

```
<?php
$arr = '[
            {
                "serial": "A",
                "timeStamp": "2018-07-28 04:00:00",
                "value1": "0.000000",
                "value2": "0.000192",
                "value3": "1.000000"
            },
            {
                "serial": "B",
                "timeStamp": "2018-07-28 04:00:00",
                "value1": "0.000000",
                "value2": "0.000191",
                "value3": "1.000000"
            },
            {
                "serial": "C",
                "timeStamp": "2018-07-28 04:00:00",
                "value1": "0.000000",
                "value2": "0.000191",
                "value3": "1.000000"
            },    
            {
                "serial": "A",
                "timeStamp": "2018-07-28 05:00:00",
                "value1": "0.000000",
                "value2": "0.000191",
                "value3": "1.000000"
            },
            {
                "serial": "B",
                "timeStamp": "2018-07-28 05:00:00",
                "value1": "0.000000",
                "value2": "0.000191",
                "value3": "1.000000"
            },
            {
                "serial": "C",
                "timeStamp": "2018-07-28 05:00:00",
                "value1": "0.000000",
                "value2": "0.000191",
                "value3": "1.000000"
            }
         ]';
//Step 1: Convert JSON to array
$arr2 = json_decode($arr, true);

//Step 2: Extract only those that have serial=A
$arr2 = array_filter($arr2, function($itm, $k){
                return $itm['serial'] == 'A';
            }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

//Step 3: Remove serial index from each filtered item 
$arr2 = array_map(function($itm){
                unset($itm['serial']);
                return $itm;
            }, $arr2);

//Step 4: Convert processed data to JSON
$arr2 = json_encode($arr2);

//Print JSON data
echo $arr2;
```